# Is it a good practice to change variable value directly from angular template

Tags: angular

I have a variable in the component:

`showModal: boolean`

And this in the template:

```
<div (mouseover)="handleHover('hover')">
```

`handleHover()` changes the value of `showModal`.

Should I use a `handleHover()` type func and point `(mouseover)` to it or is it fine to do something like this?

```
<div (mouseover)="this.showModal = true"">
```

Comment: I handle variable changing in code behind. Is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to angular it's better to keep the template simpler as much as possible if you are following the `template-driven-forms` approach. I assume you are following the template-driven forms approach. Therefore it's better to do the assignment via the component itself.

Either way is fine but for the sake of consistency and clean maintainable code, I would encourage you to follow `handleHover()` type function and point `(mouseover)` event to the particular function and do the rest.

For further clarity on these Angular issues I would strongly recommend following the A**ngular Style Guide** best practices mentioned in the **Angular Style Guide** in Official Angular Documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/accessibility).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would argue it is fine, and even preferable, to assign directly to the `showModal` variable in the template in the case that the only purpose of `handleHover()` is to set the variable `showModal`.

When reading the template, it is clear to see that only one simple assignment takes place, whereas using a function introduces the small overhead of needing to consult the `.ts` file to understand what is happening. It also then completely bypasses the need to have `handleHover()` at all (imagine how this would scale if you needed `handlePrimaryBtnHover()`, `handleSecondaryBtnHover()`, `handleSecondaryBtnClick()` etc if all these functions are doing is updating a single variable).

This is minor though and the `handleHover()` approach is definitely not bad of course.

I would say that `handleHover()` may be preferred when

- It contains >1 lines of code, e.g.

```
handleHover() {
  this.showModal = true;
  this.showModalSubject.next(this.showModal)
}
```

- The function needs to be referenced in many different places in the same template (although I still think `showModal = true` is more readable/succint for this use case)
- You want to explicitly test a TypeScript method that handles the assignment of `showModal`

Note: you do not need to include `this` when referencing variables from the template

```
<div (mouseover)="showModal = true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a **function** in your component to handle the event and update the variable, like **handleHover()**, is a **good practice** because it keeps the component's template simple also for reusability, you can use the same handler again and it's better for testing